# How to store random numbers into a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int randomNum = rnd.Next(1, 100);

            Console.WriteLine("The computer will guess your number\n Press Enter to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(randomNum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Hi there, hope you can help. I am a complete beginner at C# and im trying to learn. I am trying to make a number guessing game in VS. I have already made the normal version and all works well, however, i would now like to go one step further and have the game work the other way around. I would like the computer to guess the users number. What id like from this is for the computer to guess a number (which i can do) but if the users number is higher or lower than the guess, id like the computer to then guess either higher or lower. what i need to know, is how can i store the computers guesses so that i can then have something to work off?

many thanks
Ben

Comment: Have you learned how to make a collection (array, list, etc) in c#?

Comment: first step would be to create a `new List<int>()`. second step would be to `.Add()` the number to the list.

Comment: Are you sure you need a `List<int>`? You should be able to accomplish this by using variables to store the range of guessable numbers, rather than the constants `1` and `100`, and a `while` loop.

Comment: @gunr2171 i havent yet learnt about lists, i know about arrays. if these could help me here i will look into lists

Comment: @FranzGleichmann im not sure how to add the number to the list, could you write out a short piece of example code for me at all?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson im not sure what you mean sorry

Comment: @benjo25 i already did... the `List`-class has a method named [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You don't need a `List<T>` for this. Think about you playing the game against another person - what would you need to know to make the next guess once you are told higher or lower?

Comment: @NetMage i would need to know my min and max guesses right?

Comment: Yes. So you need to keep track of the two values. Once you know higher or lower, you can replace the appropriate one of the values with the previous guess, then compute a new guess.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you would like to get a number randomly and store it to the list.

Firstly, as others suggested, you can create a list.

Second, I think it is better for you to use the while statement to deal with the guess game problem.

Finally, you can try the following code to achieve it.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            int index=0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                int randomNum = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                list.Add(randomNum);
                if(index==5)
                {
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I will try this later and try and break it down and learn each part

Comment: @benjo25,Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.